# How to use multiple cases in ruby

Tags: ruby

When I navigate to "rent" page "without" filter

```
  case value and filter
    when "sale", "with"
      puts "1"
    when "rent", "with"
      puts "2"          
    when "sale", "without"
      puts "3"
    when "rent", "without"
      puts "4"          
  end
```

> Expected output: 4
>
> Actual output: 3

In the above statement it doesnt throw error but fail to work as expected. the case `value` is not accounted.

Is there any tweek to use multiple cases. here, I need to account both "**value**" and "**filter**"

Comment: Oops! I didn't mean "*was marked as an exact duplicate of an existing question*" I mean "*this question has an answer*".

Comment: @PrashanthSams: this question IS a duplicate. Take a look at the second snippet in the tokland's answer to the linked question.

Comment: sure @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it worked!!!

Comment: Note that `value and filter` will _evaluate_: since `value` is `"rent"` (and not `nil` or `false`), the result is `filter` (i.e. `"without"`). You then proceed to find the first `when` that contains a `"without"` clause, which is the third option. You cannot "bind" two values using `and` to jointly use later; it will always be one or the other, as defined by the semantics of that operator.

Comment: In your case maybe it's better to write like this: 
case [value, filter] 
when ["sale", "with"] then p '1'
<and so on>
end